# Is "having been" correct?

Tags: grammaticality, syntactic-analysis

Or is there a better way to frame this sentence:

'With the film having been released on 1st of October, the studio is looking forward to big changes for the future.'

To me it doesn't feel like having been is right in that sentence, but I don't care about what I feel, I want to know what's the correct way of writing this. 
Thank you.

Comment: It's not wrong to use "having been released" there. And there is no "correct" way of writing anything. There are just bad ways, good ways, and better ways.

Comment: And what @Robusto thinks is a bad way Drew might think is a good way, or vice versa. ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your statement is correct but can sound better with a couple minor changes:

> With the film's release on the 1st of October, the studio is looking
>   forward to big changes for the future.